# Cannot move UIView onto UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I'm creating a chat application in Objective-C. My conversation panel has two items, text field and table which will show messages. I'm using a UIView for text field and its button and this view is at the bottom of screen. Whenever I start typing, keyboard appears and as you can guess, text field is not visible.

I know using scroll views but this time, scroll view is not very suitable since I don't want table view to move up. Using a TableViewController instead of ViewController is an option for footer but in this option, if there's no message, footer goes top.

Thus, I'm using a ViewController and moving the view including text field programmatically. My code is:

```
- (void) keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
        NSValue* keyboardFrameEnd = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
        CGRect keyboardRect = [keyboardFrameEnd CGRectValue];
        [self.textFieldViewBottomConstraint setConstant:+(keyboardRect.size.height)];
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    }];
}
```

This code works when there's no table view. I see my view goes up. However, as there is a table view, the view and text field is still staying invisible. They are under the table view.

How can I do this? How can I move a view onto table view?

Comment: use https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding Which will solve your problem

Comment: Do you have a constraint between your textfield and tableview?

Comment: No, at first i had but then i removed it. I thought that would be a conflict problem. @Losiowaty

Comment: I meant of course the textfield view, sorry :) Can you show how are your constraints setup then? Also, just in case, please double check that your outlets are connected.

Comment: I got it :) My table view has constaints, top (top layout guide), bottom (bottom layout guide), leading and trailing. The view has height, bottom (bottom layout guide), leading and trailing. I change the bottom constraint of the view. I hope i'm clear. @Losiowaty

Comment: By the way, i tested my code as i mentioned. When there's no table view, the view goes up as i wanted. The table view makes it invisible since the view goes under it. @Losiowaty

Comment: Can you please print the frame of the view containing textfield when keyboard is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly, your textField containing view is going below tableView.

> Try giving constraints as, tableview top to superview and the view top
>   to tableview

and give other constraints. Take an outlet for top contraint of tableView. When you recieve keyboardWasShown change top constraint to some satisfying -ve value and when keyboard is dismissed again set the previous constraint for tableview top. I was previously working on this type of situation and this approach had worked for me, and might work for you.

or, if you really want to move the view above the tableView try using

`self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.yourView)`

it will avoid the view to go below tableview.

Comment: Thank you! Your final solution is exactly what i was looking for. Bringing subview to front :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try `IQKeyboardManagerSwift`. You just need to create one Bridge-Header.h file. Bridge it and add one line in `AppDelegate.m` file in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

> `IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true`

No need to do any thing after that, it will add Next, Previous, Done button over keyBoard in every field. Also view will become scrollable without doing any thing.

Comment: Thank you, it works for moving text field as scroll view but i don't want my table view to go upside. This is doing. Do you know anyting about partial movement with this framework?

Comment: TableView has scrolling. So when there is space to scroll it will start scrolling. You can disable scrolling when any textField become active and enable scrolling when textField resign respond. Hope it will work for you. Do not forget to up vote and accept answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the answer. I did the same with scroll view but the result is not what i wanted. Still thank you for your help.